# Accepting unkown users in Skype, any threat for malware?

Tags: skype, virus, spam-prevention

Occasionally (as in once per week or so) I receive contact requests, but don't recognize the username. Sometimes this is simply because someone I know uses a username I am not aware of, but just as often it is some spam agency, auto-bot, or Indian company trying to sell their services.

When only accepting someones request, i.e. to find out whether it is genuine, do I run into any risks? My main guess is: the risk of receiving more spam (as you appear "alive") and that, as long I don't accept files or links, there should be no real virus threat.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Skype but if it's at least half-decent you don't have to worry about it - unless of course you click on links or accept file transfers. Google to see if there are any security issues regarding that, being such a widely used software there should be some reports on it - and probably a security update - if in fact that is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried googling before posting, didn't find a serious report, but maybe my googling skills are lacking ;)